# Simulating keystrokes to the active window in Linux using XSendEvent is not working

Tags: c, linux, x11, gtk3

I'm trying to send keystrokes to the active window in Linux, which I am doing in Windows with SendInput.

The code below is based on [this page](http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html).

The code is not working under Linux however. I tried several variations without success, including sending a key release event for the keys involved first (relevant code commented out below, in auto_key).

I am not getting any errors, or warnings. It simply does not send the keystrokes. I cannot tell whether the event is incorrect, or whether the active window isn't being targeted properly.

I have a pair of functions defined like this:

```
XKeyEvent createKeyEvent(Display *display, Window win, Window winRoot, int press, int keycode, int modifiers) {
    XKeyEvent event;

    event.display     = display;
    event.window      = win;
    event.root        = winRoot;
    event.subwindow   = None;
    event.time        = CurrentTime;
    event.x           = 1;
    event.y           = 1;
    event.x_root      = 1;
    event.y_root      = 1;
    event.same_screen = True;
    event.keycode     = XKeysymToKeycode(display, keycode);
    event.state       = modifiers;

    if(press)
        event.type = KeyPress;
    else
        event.type = KeyRelease;

    return event;
}

void auto_key(int keycode, int modifiers) {
    XKeyEvent event;
    Window winFocus;
    int revert;

    /* Get X11 display */
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    if (!display) return;

    /* Get root window, and focused window */
    Window winRoot = XDefaultRootWindow(display);
    XGetInputFocus(display, &winFocus, &revert);

    /* Key release
    event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, 0, keycode, modifiers);
    XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event); */

    /* Keypress */
    event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, 1, keycode, modifiers);
    XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);

    /* Wait a tad */
    g_usleep (10000);

    /* Key release */
    event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, 0, keycode, modifiers);
    XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);

    XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

I call it with this:

```
auto_key(XK_C, GDK_CONTROL_MASK)
```

I've tried several variations, including without a mask - without success.

Comment: you need an Xflush after your send event or its going to take a very long time

Comment: That did it, thank you.